# Mailchimp response formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to format a response from a Mailchimp form:

> 0 - Please enter a value

Specifically, I want to get rid of the

> 0 -

in the very beginning of it. So I am trying to find a *digit/space/word/space* pattern in the very beginning of the string and remove it:

```js
var str = '0 - Please enter a value';
var strFormatted = str.replace('/^\d\s\w\s/i', '');

alert(strFormatted );
```

However, this code doesn't do the required. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this format is persistent ?

Comment: That's what I get when an empty form is submitted. Other responses don't seem to have any numeration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code to:

```
var strFormatted = str.replace(/^\d\s-\s/i, '');
```

without the single quotes.

`\w` does not match a hyphen but `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so you could use only `-`

[`^\d\s-\s`](https://regex101.com/r/Dm7ss7/1/)

```js
var str = '0 - Please enter a value';
var strFormatted = str.replace(/^\d\s-\s/i, '');
console.log(strFormatted);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.